# Does not graph the image with QPixmap()

Tags: python, pyqt6, qlabel, qpixmap, qvboxlayout

Good morning colleagues,

I am developing a small project in Python, as a free practice using the PyQt6 framework, and I want to show an image with the QPixmap library using a QLabel and I enter this in a vertical Layout, but when I run the program it does not graph the image and It doesn't give me any errors either

```
def generate_reproductor_tab(self):
    main_V_box = QVBoxLayout()
    button_h_box = QHBoxLayout()
    buttons_cointainer = QWidget()
    
    **song_image = QLabel()
    pixmap = QPixmap("PYQT6\Reproductor\images\song_image.png")
    song_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    song_image.setScaledContents(True)**
    
    button_repeat = QPushButton("Repeat")
    button_before = QPushButton("Before")
    button_play = QPushButton("Play")
    button_next = QPushButton("next")
    button_random = QPushButton("Random")
    
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_repeat)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_before)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_play)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_next)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_random)
    
    buttons_cointainer.setLayout(button_h_box)
    main_V_box.addWidget(song_image)
    main_V_box.addWidget(buttons_cointainer)
    self.reproductor_cointainer.setLayout(main_V_box)
```

Comment: @musicamante Somewhat ironically, the escapes are messed up in your comment. You need to use double backticks, because a backslash escapes *everything* (including backticks) inside comments. So entering `\`\`\\`\`` and `\`\`\\\`\`` will get ``\`` and ``\\``.

Comment: @ekhumoro Damn, I started editing wanting to fix that, but I got distracted by another typo and forgot about it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @sebastianBerrio Ensure that the path is correct, and consider you're using a relative path: if the *working directory* is not the one containing that `PYQT6` folder, it won't work. As a rule of thumb you should always use absolute paths or construct them based on the `__file__` variable. Also, ``\`` is an escape character, and should always be avoided for paths (no matter the absurd Windows convention): either double-escape it (``\\``) or use the standard forward slash as directory separator. If it still doesn't work (and you're *absolutely* sure about the path), please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Hi, your help helped me. Thanks